# How to convert a list of objects to a list of strings in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a List where GetData is a class. My requirement is to get all the rows of a column and add a prefix "Week" to it in order to get the data in JSON format for kendo charts.

Here is my code,

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    lstweeks = new List<GetData>()
    {
         new GetData{week = dr["WK"].ToString()}
    };

         var item = lstweeks.ToList();
         lst1.Add(item.ToString());
         lstweeks.Clear();
}
```

The result of lstweeks is : {"week":"42", "week":"43", "week":"44"}

I want to add this to another list of strings (lst1) so that I can concat lst1 with other string values. But when I try to add lstweeks to lst1, I get this result:

```
["System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WcfService1.GetData]",
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WcfService1.GetData]",
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WcfService1.GetData]",
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WcfService1.GetData]",
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WcfService1.GetData]"]
```

How can I convert my lstweeks to list of strings lst1.

P.S. I tried defining the List (lst1) as List, in that case, I get the following result in the browser.

[image]

Let me know how can I solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: override `ToString` in your class `GetData` to return Week with its value

Comment: Title of the post says "convert to string" but body talks about JSON. Please make sure you align title, body and code sample to talk about the same thing... (And make sure to search for duplicates on how to convert to JSON).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. It was very simple.

Updated code,

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    lstweeks.Add(
    {
         new GetData{week = dr["WK"].ToString()}
    );
}
```